# dipole in a dielectric sphere

Tags: electromagnetism

> I rather stuck on this homework question. I have been working on it for 3 days. I need a little help.

## Context

A point dipole **p** is placed at the centre of a dielectric sphere with permittivity $\varepsilon$ and radius $R$.

A set of axes are chosen with the origin at the centre of the sphere and the dipole aligned along the z-axis.

The overall question is to find the electrostatic potential inside and outside of the sphere. I am stuck on a sub question.

Hint. In the usual notation, pose:

$$\Phi_{in}(r,\theta)=\frac{p \cos(\theta)}{4\pi \varepsilon r^2}+\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}A_{l}r^{l}P_{l}\cos(\theta)$$ in $r<R$

$$\Phi_{out}(r,\theta)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_{l}}{r^{l+1}} P_{l}\cos(\theta)$$ in $r>R$

where $p=|\textbf{p}|$.
Use the boundary conditions to determine the $A_{l}$,$B_{l}$.

## Question:

The boundary conditions here are:

$$(\textbf{D}_{out}-\textbf{D}_{in})\cdot \hat{\textbf{r}}=\sigma$$
$$\sigma=0  \color{blue}{ \text{   across  }}r=R$$
$$\Rightarrow(\textbf{D}_{out}-\textbf{D}_{in})\cdot \hat{\textbf{r}}=0$$

$$(\textbf{E}_{out}-\textbf{E}_{in})\times \hat{\textbf{r}}=\textbf{0}\color{blue}{ \text{   across  }}r=R$$

> Show that these lead to here:
>
> $$\lim_{r\rightarrow R^{+}}(\varepsilon_{0}\frac{\partial \Phi_{out}}{\partial r})=\lim_{r\rightarrow R^{-}}(\varepsilon\frac{\partial \Phi_{in}}{\partial r})$$

## Notes

$\textbf{D}$ is called the electric displacement
$$\textbf{D}=\varepsilon \textbf{E}$$